# Best way to copy Data from one DataTable to another DataTable with diffrent structure

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, ado.net

I am copying data from DataTable to another DataTable with a structure.
I have to hardcode columns number in the loop and copy the data in object array.

What will be the best way to achieve it ?

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from vendInv in VendorInvoiceStagingTable.AsEnumerable()
                             where vendInv.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number) == InvoiceHeader
                             select vendInv;

Object[] obj = new Object[10];
var item = query.First();

for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
{
    obj[idx] = item[idx];
}

VendorInvoiceTable.Rows.Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why you want to copy the data to an array before putting it into the VendorInvoiceTable, but either way:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from vendInv in VendorInvoiceStagingTable.AsEnumerable()
                             where vendInv.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number) == InvoiceHeader
                             select vendInv;

// Would this be ok?
VendorInvoiceTable.Rows.Add(query.First().ItemArray);

// ...or if not, how about this?
object[] sourceData = query.First().ItemArray;
object[] targetData = new object[sourceData.Length];
sourceData.CopyTo(targetData, 0);
VendorInvoiceTable.Rows.Add(targetData);
```

Comment: Add method takes array of objects

Comment: DataRow.ItemArray is an object[], and so is targetData... am I missing something?

Comment: Since source contains less columns then the target. I will get expection.

Comment: Oh, ok - so you only want to select and copy a subset of the columns from vendInv? You could do that by selecting an anonymous type instead of the whole object, so instead of 

select vendInv;

...you use:

select new { vendInv.Column1, vendInv.Column2, vendInv.ColumnN };

Comment: targetData has length 10 in my case while source have 30 elements , so options will not work.

Comment: If you want to only copy 10 of source's 30 elements, you can select which 10 you want using an anonymous type in the query. query.First().ItemArray will then return an array with only 10 members.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, check out *Adapter pattern*, it will allow you to adapt the structure of one data table to another. A simple explanation and sample code can be found at [Dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx).